# GCP free trial charged me 50 Rs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I am from India .I used my credit card to sign up for Google Cloud Platform Free trial and 300$.
But It charged me Rs. 50 extra while verifying along with Rs. 2.
Why in the name of God, Google is doing this.
Charging money for free trial.
Its not fair.
Guyz help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial) says this:

After signing up, you might notice a $0-1 transaction from Google, which is a pending authorization request between our billing system and the bank that issued your credit or debit card. Authorizations might be converted to local currency by your bank, and these transactions might appear as pending on your statement for up to a month. Please keep in mind they are authorization requests only, not actual charges.

So, I think all of those charges are only authorization requests not real charges. Because 50 + 2 Indian Rupee equals 0.819 US Dollar.

If you aren't sure about this, I recommend you to talk with your bank or you can also contact to [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)

Comment: ya i found above info. in google support.Thanks for ur input:)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, when contacted GCP support, they said that it will be held as pending transaction at bank end and will be credited to customer's bank account within 45-60 days.